# What does Zizek mean?

Tags: zizek

He says firstly: There is thus no need to post a magic "downward" causality, the ability of "higher" ideal (Dennet: "design") processes to causally determine the "lower" mechanical processes, to break their causal chain:   "**the causality of freedom is purely reflexive-transitive, it is a causality which determines which causality will determine us**."

I don't really understand set theory that well, so if thats what he's referring to some clarification would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add citations for the quotes?

Comment: Zizek S.,(2006), *The Parallax view*, ch.4 The loop of freedom, (pp. 200-250): a passage on p.243/4.